# Swift MapKit Autocomplete

Tags: swift, autocomplete, mapkit, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

I am trying to set an address autocomplete in my view controller so users do not have to type the whole address and instead select it from below the search textfield. This is how my controller looks like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit


extension AddNewAddressViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results
        searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // handle error
    }
}

class AddNewAddressViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        searchCompleter.delegate = self

        searchCompleter.queryFragment = addressSearch.text!

        searchResultsTableView.dataSource = self

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var addressSearch: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchResultsTableView: UITableView!


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let searchResultsCount = searchResults.count
        return searchResultsCount
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchResult.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchResult.subtitle
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }


    @IBAction func defaultAddressButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func addAddressButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

I am getting an error that says:

> Type AddNewAddressViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the underscore for first parameter of the cellForRowAtIndexPath declaration, which is required under swift 3.0:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
[etc.]
```

As a result, you don't have a required function matching the expected signature.